# How to insert transaction into table in mysql keeping it unique for every user

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

Hey i am a newbie in web development and i am having a problem in my Cashbook Web application using servlets
I have two tables in my DB 
Users(Primary-key P_ID) and Transactions(Primary-key T_ID)
Now whenever  USER-A adds a transaction into Transaction table it is also visible to USER-B when he logs in to my web application. Is there a way that whatever transaction USER-A added to Transaction table into DB is only visible to USER-A and not to any other USER? 
So when USER-B logs in he can see only USER-B transactions not of USER-A.
Thanks.Your help would be very much appreciated

Comment: That is called multitenancy, and there are a lot of ways to implement. Perhaps you just add a user id to each transaction and use it to filter when selecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution (without multitenancy or other things) is to have a Foreign Key in Transactions table to User table, then you can filter on user and vice-versa or use JPA to do something like: user.getTransactions()

Comment: I added a foreign key (UserId) in my Transactions table,
But how do i write a sql query which inserts a transaction matching with UserId?
Here is what is tried to do
INSERT INTO cashbook.transaction (`Descrption`, `Amunt`, `TransactionType`,`Date`) VALUES ( '"+Description+"', '"+Amount+"', '"+Type+"','"+date+"')WHERE UserID='"+Login.UserId+"' "

Here UserID is what i have assigned in Users table but this query give errors?

Comment: You will have to insert the UserId along with the rest of the data, i.e. `INSERT INTO cashbook.transaction(Desc, Amt, Type, Date, UserId) VALUES (...)`
This would create the relationship between User and Transaction table which you can then query with your SELECT statements.

Comment: Thank you Brother, I did the same by adding the UserId with INSERT statement and it worked perfectly fine .
Stay blessed

Answer (score 1):

With a foreign key in transaction table to the users table, vg us_id. When a user makes a transaction fills this field with its id. Then You only show to user A those transactions where user_id is "A"....

Does this solve the problem?. :)

Comment: I added a foreign key (UserId) in my Transactions table,
But how do i write a sql query which inserts a transaction matching with UserId?
Here is what is tried to do
INSERT INTO cashbook.transaction (`Descrption`, `Amunt`, `TransactionType`,`Date`) VALUES ( '"+Description+"', '"+Amount+"', '"+Type+"','"+date+"')WHERE UserID='"+Login.UserId+"' "

Here UserID is what i have assigned in Users table but this query give errors?